# Magento2 : After setup upgrade add extention module error occur

Tags: extensions, magento2

When i add new featureslider module and run magento setup:upgrade command , this error occur and admin, front page display blank.

> File system cleanup:
>   D:/xampp/htdocs/linsenwelt/var/generation/Composer
>   D:/xampp/htdocs/linsenwelt/var/generation/Magento
>   D:/xampp/htdocs/linsenwelt/var/generation/Symfony
>   The directory 'D:/xampp/htdocs/linsenwelt/var/di/' doesn't exist - skipping >cleanup
>   Updating modules:
>   Schema creation/updates:
>   Module 'Ced_FeaturedSlider':
>
> [ReflectionException]
>   Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\AttributeFactory does not exist
>
> [ReflectionException]
>   Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\AttributeFactory does not exist
>
> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
>   Source class "\Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute" for >"Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\AttributeFactory" generation does not >exist.
>
> setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]

Please give a Solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to the Resource model of the featureslider module then upgrade the class names Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\AttributeFactory to Class Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory

Comment: Start in version 2.0.0-rc, Magento change name folder from Resource to ResourceModel

Answer (score 0):

If you Are Using Sublime Editor `Ctrl + H`

in the Bottom in Find Text Box add

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\AttributeFactory

in Replace Text Box add

> Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory

Then Run Following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
php bin/magento cache:clean
```