# upgrade to 2.1.5. composer updated but setup upgrade returns with invalid argument

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, composer, setup-upgrade

I've had  an issue with a template I purchased and needed to update it to the latest version of Magento.

I've backed up my database a files and ran: `composer update`

When this complete I ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and it has returned with:
[when setup upgrade after add extention module, error occur](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92632/when-setup-upgrade-after-add-extention-module-error-occur)

> [InvalidArgumentException]   There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

The front end of my site is now returning with:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException' with message 'The file "/h/d/ph/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Config/Composer/PackageFactory.php" cannot be deleted Warning!unlink(/home/sparkled/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Config/Composer/PackageFactory.php): Permission denied' in /h/d/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:382 

Stack trace: 
#0 /h/d/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(405): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteFile('/home/sparkled/...') 
#1 /h/d/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/home/sparkled/...') 
#2 /h/d/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403): Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File->deleteDirectory('/home/sparkled/...') 
#3 /h/d/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php(403): in /h/d/ph/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php on line 382
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue or would it be best to just use my backup to restore?
Would this be a case of doing something with `PackageFactory.php`?
Permissions are set to `0664`

Comment: would this be a case of doing something with packagefactory.php? permissions are set to 0664

Comment: Agreed, try and delete var/generation and run it again. I've just updated to 2.1.5 and received no errors.

Comment: Site has come back online after deleting var/generation however version has not updated.

Comment: maybe something went wrong in your composer update. I always delete vendor/ and change the version myself in composer.json to 2.1.5 -> http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98332/how-to-update-magento2-using-composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem and commence with the version update by doing the following:

deleted var/generation

> `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 --no-update`
>
> `composer update`
>
> `rm -rf var/di var/generation`
>
> `php bin/magento cache:clean`
>
> `php bin/magento cache:flush`
>
> `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
>
> `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
>
> `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Checked Magento version with the following command:

> `php bin/magento --version`

Complete Working.

## thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Some basic troubleshooting steps:

```
# from magento root
rm -rf vendor
rm -rf var/di var/generation var/cache
magento cache:flush # somewhat redundant
# try resetting permissions again, for instance as specified:
# http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions

# these commands take a few minutes
composer update
magento setup:upgrade
magento setup:di:compile # this may be redeundant in developer mode
```

By removing `vendor` you're letting composer do its thing. By removing those cache directories you're letting magento do its generation thing. Then, once the directory is clean, that's a good time to reset filesystem permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your store with SSH and go to the root directory of your store.

First, run the following command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 --no-update
```

Now update the composer:

```
composer update
```

Now run these commands to clean cache:

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Upgrade the setup by running this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Compile the setup by running this command:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

At last, reindex the indexers:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```