# Error when upgrading from CE 2.1.2 to 2.1.4 via Composer

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, composer

Composer version is 1.4.1

I ran `composer require magento/project-community-edition 2.1.4 --no-update` and then `composer update`

Error message returned: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` `The requested package magento/project-community-edition 2.1.2 is satisfiable by magento/project-community-edition[2.1.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.`

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer": "3.0.*",
        "magento/project-community-edition": "2.1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Installed CE 2.1.2 via Composer. How do I upgrade?

Comment: In your composer.json you set "name" to "magento/project-community-edition" and its version is 2.1.2. Maybe try setting that version to 2.1.4 also. (Or change your package name to something other than "magento/project-community-edition")

Comment: @dmatthew I changed the version to 2.1.4 and ran "composer update". Composer then deleted the core dependencies (zendframework, colinmollenhour, magento, monolog, braintree, phpseclib, league, tedivm, tubalmartin, etc) under the vendor directory. It installed & updated symfony, justinrainbow, and composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution from the answer of this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162627/upgrade-to-2-1-5-composer-updated-but-setup-upgrade-returns-with-invalid-argume?rq=1).

It seems upgrading to 2.1.4 from 2.1.2 is not possible. I tried the same upgrading procedure with 2.1.5, and it worked.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 --no-update

composer update

rm -rf var/di var/generation

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```